# What types of things break regarding building of native software when upgrading versions of Fedora, and what are some solutions?

Tags: fedora, compiling, software-updates, dist-upgrade

I do a lot of software testing and that requires me to build many different projects from source. I've recently upgraded to Fedora 33 from 31, and essentially, I have a group of issues that involve either not being able to run software that I had previously built due to "missing" dependencies, and/or when I try to build software, I get errors that packages or libraries are missing, mostly after running `./configure` or `make`, when many times, they really aren't and certainly were not knowingly removed by me. Other times, an update to a package (such as Python 3.6 -> 3.9) causes issues with some scripts, etc...

The reason why it has me confused (with exception of that python issue) at times is because, I never actually removed many of the libraries and it just seems that for whatever reason, they don't get recognized anymore, so I have to manually show the build system where they are, or just reinstall the dependencies, and so on...

Is there any general advice for clearing up these types of issues after upgrading a version of Fedora or other Linux distributions? I'd imagine this is somewhat common and while I *can* certainly troubleshoot every individual issue on a case-by-case basis, I would consider this one collective issue, and as I continue my Linux journey, would like to become more adept at addressing this issue as I upgrade in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling any non-trivial piece of software from source can be a complex task, although nowadays there's quite a bit of automation to hide much of the details. But when something goes wrong in the process, you'll need to be able to understand the process to effectively troubleshoot it.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that the knowledge and skills to troubleshoot a failing compilation process are increasingly understood as "something only the actual software developers have", while it's actually also very necessary for testers, and sometimes, highly useful for system administrators too. In fact, the underlying idea of Open Source software assumes that *everyone* should be able to recompile a software package if they feel like doing it.

---

When `./configure` complains about a missing library, it's often really looking for **the -devel package for that library**.

`./configure` is actually a shell script that runs a number of tests to find and verify the prerequisites for compiling a software package. It is generated by the `autoconf` toolkit, which is used to ease the job of making a source code package compilable on several hardware architectures and unix-like OSs.

Sometimes a library development project or a Linux distribution might make some changes in the way the development headers (`*.h` files) are laid out under `/usr/include/`. For example, an old version might have them directly under `/usr/include/`, and a newer one might have them under `/usr/include/library_name/` sub-directory.  If a library developer makes a change that is backwards-incompatible at the source level, it might be necessary to include the library version number, so that distributions may support an old version of the library as `/usr/include/library_name/` and a new version as `/usr/include/library_name2` or something. If such a change is newer than the version of `autoconf` used to create the `./configure` script for a software package, it might not be able to auto-detect the new location.

`autoconf` is not perfect, and there are also other mechanisms to supplement or replace it. Another common one is `pkg-config`: each library package that supports it will include in its `-devel` package (or equivalent) a `*.pc` file that documents important compiler options, dependencies and other information that is important when building software to use the library in question.

---

The `make` step will usually need both the actual library package and its `-devel` package to be present. When a software package is built using `make`, often several parts of it are compiled from source code to binary *object files* in isolation, and then those files are linked together to form the executable(s).

The compilation sub-step might require only the `*.h` files provided by the `-devel` package, but the linking sub-step requires that the actual library package is present.

---

If you need some piece of software compiled for OS major version X to run on OS major version (X+n), you might encounter problems with shared libraries:

- a library has undergone a backwards-incompatible change
- a library has been packaged differently to work around a name conflict or some other issue
- an old library has been completely dropped from the distribution and the functionality is now provided with a different library, or in another way altogether.

To work around problems like this, you might have to find the old libraries the software actually wants, place them into some directory that is not searched for libraries normally, and start the old program using a wrapper script that uses environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to specify a custom search path for libraries *for that application only*. See the `ld.so(8)` man page and particularly its `ENVIRONMENT` chapter for more details on things you can do to change the way an application looks for shared libraries at run-time.

In this way, I can still run a Linux version of *Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri* (copyright 1999) on a current Debian 10 system. Not too shabby, I'd say.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as opinion-based. I don't think your answer was opinion-based at all, as it addressed the exact issue I was asking about. If I put 20 people in a room and have them all upgrade from F31 to F33, chances are, several of them will run into the same exact issues, that's not opinion, that's fact. Hence why we search and find posts from others to solve our issues... There isn't much opinion about things breaking when we update software... Regardless, I wanted to thank you for your quality answer and state that I disagree with the closing reason.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any general advice for clearing up these types of issues after upgrading a version of Fedora or other Linux distributions?

- Rebuild or
- Package as snap/flatpak or
- Run in chroot or
- Run in a VM

> I'd imagine this is somewhat common and while I can certainly troubleshoot every individual issue on a case-by-case basis, I would consider this one collective issue, and as I continue my Linux journey, would like to become more adept at addressing this issue as I upgrade in the future.

That's the nature of Linux unfortunately - a fast moving target where you have to rebuild each time a new distro version gets released. That's what I do regularly for software not offered by Fedora (e.g. ffmpeg/mpv).